# task.result?.data returning null in HTTP Cloud Function call

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions

I'm [calling a Cloud Function from my app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) with the following code:

```
private fun search(g: String, l: GeoPoint): Task<String> {
    val data = hashMapOf(
        "uid" to user.uid,
        "first_name" to user.first_name,
        "age" to user.age,
        "gender" to user.gender,
        "bio" to user.bio,
        "img1" to user.img1,
        "img2" to user.img2,
        "latitude" to l.latitude.toString(),
        "longitude" to l.longitude.toString(),
        "g" to g,
        "fcmToken" to fcmToken,
        "pronoun" to if (user.gender == "male") "him" else "her"
    )
    log("data: $data") // successfully logs all values as non-null
    return functions
        .getHttpsCallable("searchNearby")
        .call(data)
        .continueWith { task ->
            log("result: ${task.result?.data}")
            // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
            // has failed then result will throw an Exception which will be
            // propagated down.
            val result = task.result?.data as String
            result
        }
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            log("search(): success $result")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            log("search(): exception $exception") // exception kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String
            log("search(): localMsg ${exception.localizedMessage}") // localMsg null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String
            log("search(): cause ${exception.cause}") // cause null
            log("search(): msg ${exception.message}") // msg null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String

        }
}
```

Why is `task.result?.data` returning `null` if every item in `data` is non-null?

**EDIT**

`.addOnFailureListener()` now returns another weird error: `HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String`.

Here is my cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
const geofirestore = require('geofirestore');
const { GeoCollectionReference, GeoFirestore, GeoQuery, GeoQuerySnapshot } = require('geofirestore');
const user = {};

exports.searchNearby = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('blocks').add({
        user1name: "1142",
        user1bio: data.bio,
        user1img1: data.img1,
        user1img2: data.img2,
        user1fcmToken: data.fcmToken,
        user1pronoun: data.pronoun
    }).then(result => {
        console.log("Successfully created document");
        return { result: "Successfully created document" };
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error creating document " + error);
        return { errorCreatingDocument: error };
    });
});
```

The document is successfully created, and `{ result: "Successfully created document" }` successfully gets sent back to the client, but it's still firing an exception `java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String`. Any idea what the problem is? It's also especially hard to debug because it doesn't tell you what like in my Cloud Functions the error is.

Comment: Since this likely is due to the interaction between your Kotlin code and the Cloud Functions code, please edit your question to also [include the minimum Cloud Functions code with which you can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: We need to be able to see the output of the function. It's probably not generating what you expect.

Comment: Ah I thought the error had to be in my Kotlin code. I'll now try debug my Cloud Function - thanks.

Comment: I have now added a similar problem in my edit @DougStevenson - the document is successfully created and returns a value to the client, but I'm still getting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a JavaScript object to the client from the callable function:

```
return { result: "Successfully created document" };
```

The object contains a single property named `result`.  Since your function returns an object, your client needs to assume the result from the callable is a Map.  The Map will have a single entry with key also named `result`.  This should be pretty easy to verify if you just log the value of `result` here:

```
val result = task.result?.data
```

Instead of casting this to a String, cast it to `Map<String, *>`, and fetch the entry named `result` out of it:

```
val data = task.result?.data as Map<String, *>
val result = data["result"]
```

Or, you can change your function to return a string instead of a JavaScript object:

```
return "Successfully created document";
```

Comment: Thankyou I missed the cast there - changing it to `Map<String, *>` fixed the issue